# Circle Rotation onTouch

Tags: java, android, geometry

Circle Rotation onTouch Only works when clicked once after that it does not do anything.

here is my code:

```
    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int n = 0;
            postInvalidate();
            for(int i=0; i<360; i++){
                setRotationX(n + 1);
            }
            forceLayout();
```

i hope someone can help me.
how can i look the code so it works multiple times?

Comment: Is not easier to just start animation after touch?

Comment: thanx for the comment, but how can i make such an animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the goodm solution, you should to add in your manifest this:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

This is for ICS and pre-ICS.

Comment: I only know that, with that code all the animations and toasts work fine.

Answer (score 1):

To do animation you need to create a folder "anim" in res folder and add such a xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:fromDegrees="0" 
    android:toDegrees="360" 
    android:pivotX="50%" 
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="1000"/>
```

in your java class try:

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.yourAnim);
a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
    {
        animPlaying = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
    {
        animPlaying = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){}
});

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
        int n = 0;
        postInvalidate();
        if(aninmPlaying == false)
        {
             yourView.startAnimation(a);
        }
        forceLayout();
```